# E: Unable to locate package libsane-extras

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scanning

I am trying to install the `sane` package in ubuntu 20.04 to be able to use a scanner but for some reason I cannot install the libsane-extras package.

```
admin:~$ sudo apt-get install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsane-extras
```

What can I do to install?

Fun fact: A few months ago, simple scanner recognized my HP scanner model

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Linux support questions should be posted to [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].